# I'm trying to convert a binary number to a decimal number but my Output is always 0

Tags: java, binary

Here is my code. I tried to Convert the binary to a Char array, then multiply each char in the array by 2 to the power of its corresponding number in the array, then sum up all the values of the char array into a double. New to programming so a bit confused. My input Binary is txfBinaryInput, and my output label is lblDisplay.

```
 private void btnProcessActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)                                           
{                                               
    if (txfBinaryInput.getText().equals(""))
    {
        lblDisplay.setText("ERROR: NO INPUT");
    } else
    {
        int n = 0;
        int[] binaryValueStorage = new int[100];
        double[] decimalValueStorage = new double[100];
        String binaryInput = txfBinaryInput.getText();
        int binaryNumber = binaryInput.length();
        char[] binaryDigits = binaryInput.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i >= binaryNumber; i++)

        {
            binaryValueStorage[n] = binaryDigits[n];
            decimalValueStorage[n] = binaryValueStorage[n] * (Math.pow(2, n));
            n++;
        }
        double sum = 0;
        for (double a : decimalValueStorage)
        {
            sum += a;
        }
        lblDisplay.setText("The Deciaml Value Is " + sum);
    }
}
```

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I assume you're new to programming.  Once your code works, it's totally fine if you're just learning basic programming.  I'll point out, however, that there is a lot inefficiency in your code.  If all you want do is come up with 'sum', you could be doing it with much less effort.  I'll throw out just one idea now: Why create the binaryValueStorage and decimalValueStorage arrays, just to turn around and sum up all of the values in it and discard the arrays?  You could just initialize 'sum' before your first loop and just directly add the computed value for each binary digit to that variable.

Comment: ie: sum += binaryDigits[i] * Math.pow(2, n)

Comment: Also, your code isn't going to work because you're expecting the character '1' to have a value of 1.  But doesn't.  It has the ascii value of declmal 49.  '0' has the ascii value '48'.

Comment: Thanks Steve, how would I fix that ascii problem?

Comment: ...and why are you using the 'double' type at all.  Isn't it true that you will always be computing integer values?

Comment: There are numerous ways.  The most forward is to just do a test for the character '1' and then you don't need its value at all

Comment: gosh.  sorry, but you're just way off on this whole thing.  you're also interpreting the bits in the wrong order.  you want the last digit to have the lowest value given to the pow() function, not the first digit.

Comment: Realized how off I am, will do some research and rewrite it. I was using the double because I got a possible lossy conversion error when using an int for the Math.pow

Comment: You shouldn't get any lossiness from Math.pow().  Even if you did, assigning to an int would fix that.  This way, you'd end up preserving any noise that came out of that function, which you don't want.  You want integers.  so work with integers.  As far as the ascii question, the simplest way to turn a character into a digit is to realize that you want to compute "how far your character's value is from the value of character '0'".  So the decimal value for '3' is ('3' - '0') == 3.  So for n, knowing it's a decimal digit, the decimal value is (n - '0')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beware: in your for loop condition, you have `i >= binaryNumber` instead of `i < binaryNumber`, therefore your program will never enter the loop!

And on a side note, why are you using two variables, `i` and `n`, for the same purpose (incrementing and accessing the array)?

**Edit:** another issue:

In binary numbers, lower order bits are *to the right*, but in arrays, indices are *from left to right*!!

So you want **your rightmost digit** to be multiplied by 2^0, the next one right to its left by 2^1, and so on.

But in your code, what is happening is the opposite: it is the leftmost digit (your digit at index 0) that is being multiplied by 2^0!

To fix, you can either:

1) *reverse* your `binaryDigits` array before starting to convert, and keep the rest of your code untouched

2) replace `decimalValueStorage[n] = binaryValueStorage[n] * (Math.pow(2, n));` by `decimalValueStorage[n] = binaryValueStorage[n] * (Math.pow(2, binaryNumber - n));`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks so much. Fixed the < > problem and replaced the n's with i's, I understand my mistakes, but my final output is still wrong ]. Binary input 1 gives a decimal output of 49, which is very wrong, and I've noticed certain values such as 11 causes an error in the problem. Any ideas/

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a lot to throw at you, but this is how I'd attack this problem:

```
public class BinaryToDecimalTest {

    private static long binaryToDecimal(String binaryInput)
    {
        long sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0 ; i < binaryInput.length() ; i++) {
            sum *= 2;
            if (binaryInput.charAt(i) == '1')
                sum += 1;
        }
        return sum;
    }

    private static void test(String binaryInput) {
        long n = binaryToDecimal(binaryInput);
        System.out.println(String.format("The Deciaml Value of %s Is %d", binaryInput, n));
    }

    public static void main(String...args) {
        test("0100");
        test("1011");
        test("1011");
        test("10000000");
        test("10000000000000000");
    }
}
```

Result:

```
The Deciaml Value of 0100 Is 4
The Deciaml Value of 1011 Is 11
The Deciaml Value of 1010 Is 10
The Deciaml Value of 10000000 Is 128
The Deciaml Value of 10000000000000000 Is 65536
```

I don't want to just hit you with code, but I didn't know where to start given all of the issues with your code.  I wanted you to see how directly you can often attack a problem.  I'd be happy to keep working with you, and explain what's going on here.

The one dirty trick I'm using is multiplying the entire accumulated sum by two each time around.  This lets you work naturally from the front of the array, rather than having to work your way backwards.  The first digit gets multiplied by 2 (length - 1) times, the second (length - 2) times, etc., down to the last number, which doesn't get multiplied at all.

Comment: This is really helpful. I understand how you used sum *= 2 and the charAt(i) to build up the binary value and convert it to a decimal (took me a while). Thank you so much for your help. Just to confirm I'll quickly explain what  I think the code is doing.

Comment: the for statement declares int i and that the process will repeat until i is no longer smaller than the lentgh of the binary number and that after each run of the code, the value of i will increase by one. sum *= 2 is used to multiply the value of the forming decimal by 2 so that by the time we reach the end of the binary, the 7th digit would have experineced the *2 seven times ect. The charAt(1) and sum += 1 adds the value 1 to the decimal if the binary value is one, and this one will be multipled by 2 () times and added to the decimal simultameously. I hope this brief explaination is correct

Comment: Right on!  It makes me happy that you can get that level of understanding from what I did. - one very minor correction...the 7th digit will experience *2 (7 - 1) times because the 1st digit should experience the *2 (7-7) == no times.  Notice that we multiply * 2 FIRST, and THEN add the next digit.  This is why it comes out to be (length - 1) for the first digit.

Comment: I'll point out that a side effect of only testing for "binaryInput.charAt(i) == '1'" is that any character in the input string is acceptable, and every character other than '1' is treated like '0'.  You could also test for '0' so that you could throw an error if the tested character isn't either '1' or '0'. - if it was me, I'd get complicated and ignore spaces completely, to allow breaking the number into clumps of binary digits.  This would require a little more logic in the loop to not do the multiply when you see a space character.